# Extend On-premise AD to Azure

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I want to be able to provision Azure VMs and attach them to on-premise AD. I have read the Azure documentation and there is a requirement for a site-to-site VPN connection.In my case, having a VPN device is not feasible. Would it be possible to do the same with a point-to-site VPN connection? I haven't seen any guidance on the Azure website regarding the same.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-install-replica-active-directory-domain-controller/

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't considered using Point-to-site where my `point` would be my whole on-premises network, I can assure you that you do not need a special VPN device to make Site-to-Site VPN with Azure.

Check [this dedicated article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn636917.aspx) on how to create Azure Site-to-Site VPN with Windows Server Routing and Remote Access.